How does this wormhole effect shader create a distortion?
Below is the code for a simple wormhole effect shader made in shadertoy.com.
I understand everything else except:
    uv.x = time + .1/(r);
    uv.y = time + sin(time/2.575) + 3.0*a/3.1416;

Here's what I think it's doing:

uv.x = time + .1/r is making the later texture() take the color for the pixel from the right side of the wormhole's texture, making it look like it's moving forward. And I think the +.1/r is there to make the center of the wormhole to distort more.

I have no idea what the uv.y is doing.


void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    float time = iTime;
    vec2 p = -1.0 + 2.0 * fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec2 uv;
       
    p.x += 0.5*sin(time);
    p.y += 0.5*cos(time*1.64);
    
    float r = length(p);
     
    float a = atan(p.y,p.x); 
    uv.x = time + .1/(r);
    uv.y = time + sin(time/2.575) + 3.0*a/3.1416;
   
    float w = r*r;
    vec3 col = texture(iChannel0,uv).xyz;
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}

